# If functions per $row in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that shows me data from a call flow. 
I need the Data from this table to be manipulated per row in such a way that all the values of my table, which are being looked up from my DB, (which are now in code) will be translated into a text value. Let me show U and explain:

My Table:

```
<?php
include_once "Connect2Martijn1.php"; 
?>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSMartijn1.css">
   </link>



<head>
   <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
   <meta name="description"content="VoizXL ">
   <meta name="keywords"content="VoizXL ">
   <meta name="author"content="Kenn Lo-A-Tjong">
   </meta>
   <title>Call Flow</title>


</head>



<fieldset>
<article class="rondehoeken"> 
<header>
    <div class="streep1"></div>
    <div class="streep2"></div>
    <div class="streep3"></div>
    <div class="streep4"></div>
    <div class="streep5"></div>
    <h1 id="artikel-titel" >Call Flow</h1>
</header>

<div id="artikel-container">

<table class="table 1">
<thead>
 <title>Call Flow</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
    <style type = "text/css">
    table, td, th {
      border: 1px solid black;
    } 
    </style>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","voizxl_wachtrij");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Callflow");

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Nummer</th>
<th>Naam</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>";



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['calleridnum'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['calleridname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['statusAnswered'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['statusCalling'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Example of (how I want to be) Translating the Data:

```
<?php
 if ($row['statusAnswered'] ="NULL")
      {
      echo "Not Answered!";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Answered!";
      }
  ?>
```

What I want to Achieve is for eg. that the value in this table from $row['statusAnswered'] will be displayed in text as "Answered or Not Answered" if the Value of this row in the DB is NULL or Not...

How do I do this?

Right now I can only achieve to have 1 echo under the table saying Answered :S 
No Idea how to put it per $row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['calleridnum'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['calleridname'] . "</td>";
   if ($row['statusAnswered'] =="NULL"||$row['statusAnswered'] =="Null" || $row['statusAnswered'] =="null" || $row['statusAnswered'] =="")
      {
      echo "<td>Not Answered!</td>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "<td>Answered!</td>";
      }

  echo "<td>" . $row['statusCalling'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Dear Deepanshu,

Thank you for ur fast reply!
After editing these changes in my script, I noticed that now ALL rows in statusANswered column echo "Answered". 
But in the database not all rows in this column have the value of NULL..
Meaning that I think this script is only targeting 1 row in the column and changing the value for the whole column (all rows in this column) and this is not right..
Any Idea how to fix this issue?
Thnx ina dvanced!

Comment: @Kentje its not like that, can you tell me what values are there in your answered column in db

Comment: @Kentje is it "NULL" or "Null", on the basis that you need to compare value in your if condition

Comment: Perfect! :) Thank you Sooo Much Deepanshu! Its Works Perfect!

U are the best!
Wish I could vote u Up ut have not enough Rep!

Thank u so much again!

Comment: and you were using "=" in your if condition, it should be "==" in if condition

Comment: oh its ok !! I am glad it helped

Comment: there is a tick symbol below the upvoting symbols, select it

Answer (score 2):

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
if (!isset($row['statusAnswered']))
{
      $answered = "Not Answered!";
}
else
{
      $answered =  "Answered!";
}
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['calleridnum'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['calleridname'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $answered . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['statusCalling'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
```

Comment: Dear Liam Allan, Thank you for ur fast reply! After editing these changes in my script, I noticed that now ALL rows in statusANswered column echo "Not Answered". But in the database not all rows in this column have the value of NULL.. Meaning that I think this script is only targeting 1 row in the column and changing the value for the whole column (all rows in this column) and this is not right.. Any Idea how to fix this issue? Thnx ina dvanced!

Comment: Nice! It works :) Thnx for this other way of solving this issue! 
Ur a boss yo! :)
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>Nummer</th>
<th>Naam</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>";



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['calleridnum'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['calleridname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . ($row['statusAnswered']=='NULL'?'Not Answered!':'Answered!') . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['statusCalling'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Dear Saket Bisht, Thank you for ur fast reply! After editing these changes in my script, I noticed that now ALL rows in statusANswered column echo "Answered". But in the database not all rows in this column have the value of NULL.. Meaning that I think this script is only targeting 1 row in the column and changing the value for the whole column (all rows in this column) and this is not right.. Any Idea how to fix this issue? Thnx ina dvanced!

Comment: hmm, dont know whats you having on your DB but then try to use === operator instead of == and also cahnge 'NULL' to NULL.

Comment: Thnx Saket But I alrdy got it to work :) 
But I will try em out just for sake of knowing how it might work as well! Cheers

Comment: And It Works! Nice man ! :) Another way of doing it!
Ur also a Boss m8! :) Thank you!!
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You could use;

```
$checkstatus = if($row['statusAnswered'] = NULL) { echo "Not Answered!"; } else {echo "Answered!";};
```

then call that by replacing;

```
echo "<td>" . $row['statusAnswered'] . "</td>";
```

with;

```
echo "<td>{$checkstatus}</td>"
```